Store has a variable from LaTeX Code
I would like to store as a Lua Variable and will check syntax using lualaTeX. How to do with LaTeX + LuaLaTeX String.
My MWE is:
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}
Would like to find format=acmsmall then save as a Lua Variable name is ACMSmall and match with some syntax.
I had tried using below code and not success:
\luaexec{
Filename=\directlua{tex.sprint(\luastring{\jobname})}
Filename = string.gsub(Filename,"(.*)-(.*)", "\2")
}}

How to do this?

you should provide a working example.  \luaexec is not a standard command, however you have the Lua syntax wrong, you have Filename=abc.tex but you need quotes, Filename='abc.tex' \jobname only provides (double)  quotes if there is a space in the name,

do acm submissions support luatex?


It isn't clear what transformation you intended, but this saves the filename and  the suplied ACM format option value to Lua variables, uppercases (just) acm in the format name and returns the resulting filename/format string to TeX.
\documentclass[format=acmsmall, review=false, screen=true]{acmart}


\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\directlua{
  local Filename = '\jobname'
  local acmformat = '\ACM@format'
  local result=Filename .. '/' ..acmformat:gsub('acm','ACM')
  tex.print(result)
  }
\makeatother
\end{document}


Article Filename is CSUR-2012' and formatneed to changemanuscript' if wrong found like acmsmall. Final Output LaTeX should be \documentclass[format=manuscript, review=false, screen=true]. How to achive this result using Lua?

The Syntax is Filenames = string.gsub(Filename,'Test%-([A-Z]+)([0-9]+)','\2') is wrong? How to check any letters and any numbers and replace with group like (\2 argument) using Lua?

@Balaji this is not the place for a Lua tutorial but see https://www.lua.org/pil/20.3.html  patterns use% not \  as the escape so you need %2 not \2  but if you place this in \directlua rather than a separate lua file you need to hide the % from tex so use `@percentchar
